# Hugo cannot convert type page.PagesGroup to Pages

Tags: hugo

I have a Hugo list template like this:

```
{{ range (.Paginate (.Data.Pages.GroupByDate "2006")).PageGroups  }}

<h3>{{ .Key }}</h3>
<ul>
    {{ range .Pages.ByWeight }}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ .Permalink }}">{{ if .Draft }}{{ T "draft" }}: {{end}}{{ .Title | markdownify }}</a>
        <time class="date-meta">{{ .Date.Format "Jan 2" }}</time>
    </li>
    {{ end }}
</ul>

{{ end }}
```

When I run the site like this `hugo server -D` it works fine.

When I build the site I get:

> > execute of template failed: template: _default/list.html:15:14: executing "main" at <.Paginate>: error calling Paginate: cannot convert type page.PagesGroup to Pages

Turning on debug and verbose do not help.  I have:

```
content
content/web
content/web/one.md
content/web/two.md
content/web/_index.md
content/web/three.md
content/about
content/about/index.md
```

What gives?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error while writing a custom theme except it happened when running `hugo -D` or `hugo server -D`. As a workaround try wrapping it in an `if` condition to check `.Data.Pages`.

```
{{ if .Data.Pages }}
    {{ range (.Paginate (.Data.Pages.GroupByDate "2006")).PageGroups  }}
    ...
    {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```